# How do I get past the boulder in the background of Twilight Woods?

Tags: paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

In Paper Mario: The Thousand-Year Door, I am stuck in Twilight Woods.  There is a large boulder blocking the path.

Prior to this boulder, there is a depression or darkened area on the ground.  I used Flurrie to blow away the masking paper, revealing wooden slats blocking a tunnel that I have ground-pounded into.

Going through the tunnel places Mario into the background, where another bolder blocks the way.  This background rock is too high to jump over, and since I am in the background, I don't have access to any companion utilities.  No game mechanic introduced so far seems to work here.

How do I get past this boulder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoilers:

> The rock in the background is related to the rock in the foreground.  Use Mario to push right against the background rock, and the foreground rock will likewise be pushed right... revealing another hidden tunnel in the foreground.

This video starts just before you use Flurrie to blow away the first tunnel that you described: